# A.n.t landscape addon can't be enabled

Tags: add-on

I'm using blender 2.79 on Ubuntu Linux since my computer can't handle the current version of blender. when I go to enable A.N.T Landscapes it's always giving me this error message.
[image: a.n.t]

I've done all that I could think of.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: It's trying to tell you that the Python package NumPy (https://numpy.org/) can't be found, either because Blender is looking in the wrong place or the package isn't installed.   The method for installing varies depending on the version of Ubuntu you have, but if you search for 'numpy install ubuntu' you'll find instructions for the various versions.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll look into it. If it helps I just downloaded blender through the terminal.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH. I just needed to download it, and there it is. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll make my comment an actual answer. I'd appreciate it if you'd check the check on the answer for 'solved my problem' or whatever it's called. (The green check mark.)

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to tell you that the Python package [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) can't be found, either because Blender is looking in the wrong place or the package isn't installed. The method for installing varies depending on the version of Ubuntu you have, but if you search for '*numpy install ubuntu*' you'll find instructions for the various versions.

The thing about python stack trace backs is that if you're an end user, the useful information is almost always the last line, in this case

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Python has extra features like Blender, only instead of *add-on* the features are usually called *module* and once you know the name, you can usually search the web for instructions on how to install them.

Answer (score 1):

As the last line of the error says you need to install a python module called numpy. Installing it may fix it. To do so on Debian based distros like your Ubuntu type into the terminal `sudo apt install python3-numpy` . This command will install the numpy package globally and can be then seen by Blender. To be sure rather restart Blender after the installation and It should work now!